# Is there a way to tell if the user would prefer metric or imperial without asking in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, internationalization, globalization

Right now I'm doing:

```
bool UseMetricByDefault() {
    return TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now).TotalHours >= 0;
}
```

This works for distinguishing USA from Europe and Asia, but it ignores South America.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I would ignore me as well, if I was in an internet café in London. I would greatly appreciate an option to override the guess.

Comment: Of course there would be an override. Hence the "ByDefault" in the function name.

Comment: Hmm, there is a 'Measurement system' setting in Regional and Language Options under Control Panel (behind the Customize button). I wonder what that maps to in .NET.

Comment: Shouldn't everyone switch to metric? O:-))  It's kinda like... mmm... standard :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [`RegionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.aspx) class in the `System.Globalization` namespace:

```
bool isMetric = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric;
```

If you want a specific region, you can use one of the following:

```
// from a CultureInfo
CultureInfo culture = ...;
RegionInfo r = new RegionInfo(culture.Name);

// from a string
RegionInfo r = new RegionInfo("us");
```

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem is that even if you use their RegionInfo, not everyone in a region uses the same system.  In the US, scientists often use metric in their research, and here in Canada, its a bit of a mix, since we get a lot of food packaging from the US but we teach our children in metric (but only since recently - my parents still think in imperial).

That being said, you can make a fair guess using the [RegionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979201.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's already an implementation in [`System.Globalization.RegionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.aspx) (`regionInfo.IsMetric`).

You *could* use the [`CultureInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) which can return the `Culture` of the operating system you're running on - usually in the format `en-US` `en-GB` `de-DE` etc.
Cultures are more often used for translating applications from one language to another depending on the culture of the operating system.

This is all for specified localisation - you may want to read up on some tutorials and articles regarding it (ie [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/Globalization_Localization_in_DotNet_CSharp07032006023510AM/Globalization_Localization_in_DotNet_CSharp.aspx)).

Comment: Don't you mean the RegionInfo class?  CultureInfo gets this related to language - RegionInfo has things language, measurement, and currency.

Comment: Yep, yep. I've left info about `CultureInfo` in there anyway, looks like I could do with a break for a half hour or so...

Answer (score 2):

It's a property on the `RegionInfo` class:

```
// en-US, en-GB, de-DE etc.
string cultureName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo(cultureName);
Console.WriteLine("You prefer to see {0}", regionInfo.IsMetric ? "metric" : "imperial");
```

Answer (score 1):

For a "stab in the dark" the RegionInfo information is good enough.

However in practice places like the UK have exceptions. For example:

- anything traffic related is imperial
- temperatures for weather are metric, but some people prefer imperial
- measurements of equipment are metric... mostly

Much depends on the generation you're in and your attitude to change.

So - in practice - provide both, take a guess at a sensible default, but if it's important  *always allow the user to override the preference, and make sure these changes are remembered.*